What is the position of ISKCON on Diksha after the discussions held between followers of ISKCON Bangalore group and HH Jayapataka Swami Maharaj?
I found an article over the internet where there were mentions of letter exchanges between HG Madhu Pandit Das and GBC EC.
I could draw a conclusion that both the groups came to an agreement where they were ready to acknowledge HDG Srila Prabhupada's position as the eternal spiritual master and the 1st initiation i.e. the Hari Naam diksha will be given by Him posthumously and that the giver of the second initiation is the disciple's diksha guru. Link to this conversation: https://theharekrishnamovement.org/2013/12/07/sri-madhu-pandit-dasas-official-reply-to-ec/
I could not what happened next. An article suggests that HG Madhu Pandit Das met HH Gopal Krishna Goswami Maharaj in Radha Parthasarathy Mandir, New Delhi in 2019. But I want to know where is this conversation headed now.
